# How to implement generic sum function for SequenceType where Generator.Element is of type Int

Tags: swift, generics

I’m trying to write a function used in benchmarking the iteration performance of various SequenceType implementations. It should simply sum the contents of the sequence, where all elements are `Int`s. I’m struggling with expressing the generic constraint on the function...

```
func sum<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element: Int>(s: S) -> Int {
  var sum = 0
  for i in s {
      sum += i
  }
  return sum
}
```

This results in following two errors:

- Type `‘S.Generator.Element’` constrained to non-protocol type `’Int’`
- Binary operator `'+=‘` cannot be applied to operands of type `’Int'` and `’S.Generator.Element’`

Is there a way to define this function to work over any `SequenceType` implementation, with elements specialized to `Int`?

Comment: I have tried force downcast to `Int`, but that incurs slight performance penalty and distorts the results for the purpose of this function.

Comment: I am aware that I can use `reduce` function, but my purpose is to explicitly test the sequences in the `for in` loop, which has slightly different performance characteristics than `reduce`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constraint should be `S.Generator.Element == Int`:

```
func sum<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Int>(s: S) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for i in s {
        sum += i
    }
    return sum
}
```

Slightly more general for integer types:

```
func sum<S: SequenceType, T : IntegerType where S.Generator.Element == T >(s: S) -> T {
    var sum : T = 0
    for i in s {
        sum += i
    }
    return sum
}
```

Comment: I could swear I have tried that syntax… but apparently no. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Though the function proves useless for intended purpose, as of Swift 1.2, because the compiler apparently does not inline and specialize the measured SequenceType implementation and is several orders of magnitude slower than always writing the for-in loop by hand in each testcase. There appears to be some kind of special case optimization for the `reduce` function, which performs comparably to manual of-in loop.

Answer (score 0):

An updated version for Swift 3.1:

```
func sum<S: Sequence>(_ s: S) -> Int where S.Iterator.Element == Int {
    return s.reduce(0){$0 + $1}
}
```